# Fill out custom field on Sales Order Cancellation Workflow

Tags: netsuite

In need of a workflow to force a user to fill in a custom field when they cancel an order in NetSuite. We've tried some things and cannot seem to make this happen. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: use Return User Error in workflow.   Ex: in Condition Memo = Empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work, though I haven't actually tested:

- **Record Type**: Transaction
- **Sub Types**: Sales Order
- **Event Definition** - On View or Update
- **Event Types**: On View or Update
- **Trigger Types**: Before Record Submit
- **Condition**: Status is Sales Order: Closed and Custom Field is blank

Then add a "Return User Error" action which will prevent such a record from submitting.

Comment: Partial success, still one issue:

I've setup mostly as you suggest. Difference is our Condition is this: `Sales Order : Cancellation Reason Is Empty` where `Cancellation Reason` is our custom field and our Event Type is: `Cancel`. We are unsure what the current `Status` would be and thus don't check this. It does show the User Error action with our message. 

However, if we have edited the record and there is a value selected from the dropdown list in `Cancellation Reason`, it is still displaying the `User Error`. We need only to display if field is empty. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok after talking with NetSuite support we found out that our condition which had `Record Type` set to `Sales Order:` needed to have that removed. This solved our issue.